# redirecting url out of Iframe to parent window using iframe link

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am Iframing auto generated data from a platform I am using so I do not have direct access to the Iframes links. so what i was trying to do is write a script that gets the link in the Iframe then redirects the parent page with that link.

Here is the script I am using / trying to implement and i cannot see what I am doing wrong:

```
<script>
    function replaceLoad(oIframe) {
        oIframe.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("replaceLoad").contentWindow.location = "javascript:moveMe()"
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the the iframe html:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.discoverhomefinder.com/dljones/homes-for-sale/AZ/Anthem?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 3900px; margin-top: -12%; width: 100%;" onload="replaceLoad(this)">
</iframe>
```

If anyone has any insight as to what I am doing wrong this is killing my head!

Thanks!

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain as the parent window? if not, you're not going to get far.

Comment: yes it is, i just cannot edit the page that is auto generating the data so I am using the iframe

Comment: if you're binding it with `onload=""` why are you then rebinding it with `oIFrame.onload`? it's already loaded at that point (if it's made the callback) so the next binding won't fire.

Comment: I dont think i follow. are you saying i do not need `oIframe.onload`

Comment: @algib Does "gets the link in the Iframe" mean the `iframe` `src`attribute, or an `a` or `link` element within the `iframe` ? Also, does not appear to be an `id` of `replaceLoad` present at either `parent` or `iframe` ? But, rather, a  named `function` `replaceLoad` ?

Comment: `a` or `link` element within the `iframe`.
Am I not properly referencing it?